# How to get Welcome message after connecting to SSH using JSch

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

When I connect to SSH using PuTTY, I get the following message as given below.

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-98-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
deb@ubuntu:~$
```

Similarly, when I use JSch library to connect, I should also get the same message in Java. Please help me about how to get this. I provide below my code details.

```
public String connect() {
    String errorMessage = null;
    try {
      sesConnection = jschSSHChannel.getSession(userName, ipOrHostName, PORT);
      sesConnection.setPassword(password);
      sesConnection.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
      sesConnection.connect(TIMEOUT);

      //After connecting, I should get the welcome message

    } catch (JSchException jschX) {
      errorMessage = jschX.getMessage();
    }
    return errorMessage;
  }
```

I want to get the welcome message from a unix system before executing the commands in JSch. Please help about how to get it.

Comment: What kind of welcome message is that? There are many ways to implement a welcome message. See https://serverfault.com/a/653403/168875

Comment: Hi Martin, once you login to unix box using Putty, you get some initial message like version, welcome message etc. I want to grab those messages using JSch library once I connect before executing any command.

Comment: We know that. You have already said that in your question. That's not what I have asked for.

Comment: Do you get the message before or after authentication?

Comment: I want to get the message before and after authentication that is the requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are there two distinct messages?

Comment: Martin, just simply login to any unix box using putty, see what message you get after login only. That is my requirement.

Comment: Sorry, but you just keep repeating yourself. Already in my very first comment, I've pointed you to a post, where I explain that there are at least two ways how the server can feed the login message to the client. And you haven't even bothered to try to find out which of the ways your server is using. Until you do, we cannot help you, as each way needs a completely different code on JSch side.

Comment: Martin, it is not about how to display the message, it is about how to grab the stream coming into JSCH session. Thats all I have, beyond this, I do not have any info.

Comment: You completely miss the point.  Please read my comments and the linked post carefully. If you do know how to find out how the server is sending the message, at least answer the question, I've asked in my 3rd comment: *"Do you get the message **before or after** authentication?"*

Comment: Using Putty, after successfully entering username, password, I get the message.

Comment: OK, then it's a simple shell output. How do you plan to execute your commands?

Comment: Before executing any command, I want to parse the information.

Comment: I've asked *"How do you plan to execute your commands?"*

Comment: I will use something like this Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec"); and provide a command like this "/usr/lib/someDir/create user userName pwd ... ". Then I will use like this ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command1);

Comment: And that's the problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The message you are seeing is simply printed on a *shell* output.

That does not go well with automatic its reading and executing commands.

I general to automate a command execution, you correctly plan to use SSH channel "exec" (`ChannelExec` in JSch). But that channel won't give you the message.

You would have to use "shell" channel (`ChannelShell` in JSch). But that channel is intended for implementing an interactive shell session. Not to automate command execution and not for parsing command output. Particularly in the context of your question, there's no realiable way to find out the end of the "welcome message". You would have to read the output line by line, until you get the prompt (`"deb@ubuntu:~$"`).

Or, if your use case allows that, you can use `ChannelShell` to get the message and then use `ChannelExec` to execute the commands.

---

You better talk to the server administrator to make the information you need available using a different API (like using `SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_BANNER`, or even other way).
See my answer to [SSH MOTD per user](https://serverfault.com/q/653399/168875#653403) to understand the different ways how the server can provide the "welcome message". Had the server used `SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_BANNER`, you could use [`UserInfo.showMessage`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/UserInfo.html#showMessage-java.lang.String-) to capture the message. See also [How to read the SSH key-sig pair banner (for generating SSH password) after connecting to host in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40058471/850848)

Comment: Hmmm, I was expecting this. SO there is no way to grab this. By the way, I cannot tell Admin to provide. Putty provides a way to grab. Besides, it is not always necessary to connect to only Unix box, I may have to connect to a Switch(Cisco, Dell, Brocade etc).

Comment: Martin, do you want to suggest any other library to use for my requirement ?

Comment: It's not about library. It's how SSH works. But you can use `ChannelShell` to get the message and then use `ChannelExec` to execute the commands.